# Git - How to copy a specific folder from one branch to another with a different path?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I'm looking for ways to automate deployment of my GitHub project on GitHub Pages.

I have a folder `packages/client/dist/` with a deployment build in `dev` branch. I'm searching for a git command that could copy/push its contents to the root folder of `deploy` branch of my project (in order to make it available on GitHub Pages). It would be great if it could also remove all old files there before pushing.

So I need to get files go like this: `@dev/packages/client/dist/` (local) > `@deploy/` (remote).

My idea is after I make some changes in `dev` branch and run `yarn build`, I write something like `yarn deploy:ghp` that could do the above mentioned things.

I've played with `git checkout`, but it doesn't seem to do what I need. It might also be a problem that `packages/client/dist/` is in `.gitignore`. Any help/advice would be much appreciated.

I've tried the following while on `dev` branch:

```
git add -f -- ./packages/client/dist
git commit -m "chore: test deploy commit" -- ./
git push -f origin dev:deploy
```

and

```
git add -f -- ./packages/client/dist
git stash
git checkout -b deploy
git stash pop
git commit -m "chore: test deploy commit" -- ./
git push -f origin deploy
```

But it just pushed all files from `dev` to `deploy` (which was empty before) without copying the `dist` folder.

Comment: This is kind of confusing: "that could push its contents to the root folder of deploy branch". It sort of seems like you're mixing up the concept of pushing commits, with a folder structure of a workspace that has the `deploy` branch checked out. If you think of it this way, "you only push commits", and also "you checkout a specific commit and that will update your local file system", perhaps the question may change a little bit?

Comment: @TTT, sorry if it is too confusing. What I need is to get the files go like this: `@dev/packages/client/dist/` (local) > `@deploy/` (remote). Is there viable git commands for this?

Comment: `So I need to get files go like this: @dev/packages/client/dist/ (local) > @deploy/ (remote).` this isn’t a thing. You can move ‘git mv’ or copy or whatever and commit that, and push the result though.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to publish your `packages/client/dist` directory from your `dev` branch to the root of your `deploy` branch.

Starting on your `dev` branch, you could do something like this (this assumes your `gh-pages` branch already exists):

```
# check out gh-pages branch to directory gh-pages
git worktree add gh-pages gh-pages

# ensure branch is up-to-date with remote
git -C gh-pages pull origin gh-pages

# replace contents of gh-pages/ with contents of your dist directory
# note that the trailing slash on "packages/client/dist/" is important
rsync -a --exclude=.git --delete packages/client/dist/ gh-pages/

# update gh-pages branch with new content
git -C gh-pages add .
git -C gh-pages commit -m 'Deploy files'

# push branch to remote
git -C gh-pages push origin HEAD

# clean up
rm -rf gh-pages
git worktree prune
```

---

If all that seems somewhat complicated, use something like the [`ghp-import` script](https://github.com/c-w/ghp-import); with that tool, the process looks like:

```
ghp-import --push packages/client/dist
```